# How i can extract year from datetime.now?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I want user to input the year of vehicle made but not more than this year. for example today is 2015, i don't want them to input 2020. but 2016 is ok. 
here is my code.

```
    property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("VehicleYear");
    string vehicleYear = Convert.ToString(property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null));
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vehicleYear) && vehicleYear.Length == 4 && Convert.ToInt16(vehicleYear) >= 1980)
    {
        isVehicleOlderThan1981 = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isVehicleOlderThan1981 = false;     
else if (value != null && Convert.ToDateTime(value) < DateTime.Now)
{
    return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
}
```

i only want to get a year from the DatetTime.now

Sorry i am new to the programming.

Comment: "but 2016 is ok." Why? It's also in the future.

Comment: technically you can buy a 2016 year model in 2015. because of that this year + 1 year is allowed as a valid input.

Comment: @TedSakuma Ah ok. Then the requirement would be:
"input the year of vehicle made but not more than NEXT year"

Comment: Comparing just the year component of the dates is not correct. You have to compute the difference as follows: (value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 365. This is assuming by year you mean 365 days.

Comment: @FabianBigler yes exactly.

Comment: @TedSakuma OK. I provided you an answer with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to clean your code for a bit and make it more logical (Also attached the answer you are looking for):

```
    property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("VehicleYear");
    var value = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
    int inputNumber;
    //First check if input is number
    if (!int.TryParse(value, out inputNumber))
    {
      this.ErrorMessage = "Input is not an integer!"
      //you could also throw an exception here (depends on your error handling)
      return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
    }

   //retrieves the number of digits
    int countDigits = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(year) + 1);
    if (countDigits != 4)
    {
      this.ErrorMessage = String.Format("Input has {0} digits!",countDigits);
      return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
    }

    if (inputNumber > (DateTime.Now.Year + 1))
    {
      this.ErrorMessage = "Year is in the future!";
      return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
    }

    //inputNumber is now a valid year!
    if(inputNumber > 1980)
    {
       isVehicleOlderThan1981 = true;
    } else {
       isVehicleOlderThan1981 = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the year component of any date (including DateTime.Now), use this:

```
DateTime.Now.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (value != null && Convert.ToDateTime(value) > DateTime.Now.AddYears(10))
{
//validation error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.Now.Year
```

You may also want to look at TryParse methods, it will simplify your code.
ie

```
int i;
if(int.TryParse("VehicleYear", out i)
{
//successful conversion, use int i for your comparisons etc.
}
else
{
//wasn't a valid year (can't be converted)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Year `Year` property from `DateTime`. Your `else if` may look like:

```
else if (value != null && Convert.ToDateTime(value).Year < DateTime.Now.Year)
```

NOTE: `Convert.ToDateTime(value).Year` will scream at you if `value` does not have correct date.